# what's a proper way to check for null/empty string in js before including to params?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a querystring and want to exclude keys if vals are empty, what's a proper way?

```
 setQueryString: function () {
    var keyword = $('#keyword').val();
    //how to exclude it if keyword is empty?
    var params = {           
        "keyword": $.trim(keyword)
    };

    return params;
}
```

take into account, that I will have 20+ inputs like keyword..trying to avoid lots of IF statements

Comment: I think it's better design to allow null and empty values in the instantiation of your objects, and test for null values when you call for it, that way, you can save yourself a whole bunch of ifs in places you don't need it. (Maybe some other part of the program doesn't care about "keyword" being null or empty, and only needs "queryData"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set it if it's empty is all:

```
var keyword = $.trim($('#keyword').val());
var params = {};

if(keyword) {
    params.keyword = keyword;
}

return params;
```

---

**(edit)**

If you have lots of things to check, consider using either a loop:

```
var items = {
    keyword: $.trim($('#keyword').val())
    // etc.
};
var params = {};

for(var x in items) {
    if(items.hasOwnProperty(x) && items[x]) {
        params[x] = items[x];
    }
}

return params;
```

or a function of some kind, for example:

```
var params = {};

function check(name) {
    var value = $.trim($('#' + name).val());

    if(value) {
        params[name] = value;
    }
}

check('keyword');
// etc.

return params;
```

Comment: yea, but what if I have 20 more inputs to check? it will become messy code with lots of if statements. wonder if there is a cleaner way..

Comment: @StewieGriffin: Edited for other possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple params and you don't want lots of if statements:

```
setQueryString: function () {
    var params = {
        'param1': $.trim($('#param1').val()),
        'param2': $.trim($('#param2').val())
    }

    for (p in params) {
        if (params.p == null || params.p == '') {
            delete params.p;
        }
    }

    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an empty string is a falsy value in JavaScript you can simpley check if val() is true:

```
setQueryString: function () {
    var keyword = $('#keyword').val();
    if(keyword){
    var params = {           
        "keyword": $.trim(keyword)
    };

    return params;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 setQueryString: function () {
    var keyword = $.trim($('#keyword').val());


    var params = {};

    if(keyword !== undefined && keyword !== '') {
        params.keyword = keyword;
    }

    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need `extend`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/